# SoapUI 5.3.0 error: does not close tag

Tags: soapui

I am trying to create new SOAP project in SoapUI. The steps I am following are as below.

1. Mentioned URL of WSDL.

[image]

2. But while loading this receiving below error.

[image]

For this I have followed the soltution given in [this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-error-does-not-close-tag/td-p/29309) link. I
Have proxy setting on my machine. Hence I have done same setting SoapUI.

[image]

[image]

The mentioned WSDL is successfully opening in my browser also.

[image]

I do not know if I  am missing anything any settings. Any help for this problem would be appreciated.

**Note : Due to some security norms I can not revealed my URLs.**

Comment: It is clear from the screen shot that there seemed to have issue with the xml schema used in the wsdl.

Comment: @Rao No. The same WSDL is working properly in older version of SoapUI.

Comment: Why not download files locally and see if complaint is true.

Comment: @Rao I have verified the schema I haven't found any issue in the same.

Comment: @Rao see https://postimg.org/image/kg11tkbo9/ notepad++ haven't found any schema related issue in this

Comment: There is a possibility to have error in the referring / external xml schema that is being imported. Please have a check.